# What is the song in Hunter x Hunter (2011) ep. 70 at 19:00?

Tags: music, hunter-x-hunter

There's a song playing on *Hunter x Hunter* (2011) ep. 70 at 19:00. It's got strings at first and then a guitar.

I've looked all over and I can't find any versions of this song.

What is this song?

Answer (score 1):

If you are referring to ***[Hunter x Hunter 2011](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Hunter_%C3%97_Hunter_(2011)_episodes)*** Episode 70 titled "Guts × And × Courage" during the dodge ball match, the song you hear around 19:00 seems to be an instrumental version of the ending song ***[Reason](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cyq5bUXpnYI)*** by the band [***Yuzu***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yuzu_(band)). If you would like a more complete list of the music used in Hunter x Hunter than can be found here: C[***omprehensive list of Hunter x Hunter Music***](https://www.reddit.com/r/HunterXHunter/comments/3e80hw/comprehensive_hunter_x_hunter_2011_music_list/).

Comment: Thanks for the link. I have been through OST 1-3 and it's not one of the songs on those.

Comment: I cannot edit my comment. A quick search for that returns exactly what I want. THANK YOU! https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S2SRMRUF5tU